# C Find sub-symmetric matrix in one big matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I try to find all the sub-symmetric matrix in one big matrix but I only get some of the sub-symmetric matrix and some of them are incorrect.

In my function I found all the sub-matrix and try to send all the square sub-matrix to function that check if the sub-matrix is symmetric, If the sub-matrix is symmetric I print the matrix.

main -

```
int main() {
    int matrix[][8] = {{1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9},
                        {2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                        {3, 4, 6, 2, 5, 6, 7, 86},
                        {9, 5, 8, 3, 6, 8, 9, 8},
                        {6, 7, 1, 4, 7, 9, 1, 9}};
    findSubMatrix(matrix, 5, 8);

    return 0;
}
```

findSubMatrix -

```
void findSubMatrix(int matrix[][8], int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= cols; j++) {
            for (int m = 0; m <= rows; m++) {
                for (int n = m; n <= rows; n++) {
                    if (n - m == j - i && n - m > 0) {
                        if (isSymmetric(matrix, i, j, m, n) == 1) {
                            for (int k = m; k <= n; k++) {
                                for (int l = i; l <= j; l++) {
                                    printf("%d ", matrix[k][l]);
                                }
                                printf("\n");
                            }
                            printf("\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

isSymmetric -

```
int isSymmetric(int matrix[][8], int rowStart, int rowEnd, int colStart, int colEnd) {

    for (int i = colStart; i < colEnd; i++) {
        for (int j = rowStart; j < rowEnd; j++) {
            if (matrix[j][i] != matrix[i][j]) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I appreciate any help Thanks.

Comment: Besides the fact that you have a 5 rows x 8 columns matrix (but you are passing 8 and 5 to `findSubMatrix`), are you sure you are calculating the indices in `isSymmetric` correctly?

Comment: @Bob__ I update the matrix bounds, but I not sure about the indices in isSymmetric

Comment: Hm. Apart from the mix-up Bob mentioned, you also swap the meanings between `findSubMatrix` and `isSymmetric`. Looping over all possible sub-matrix dimensions and then picking those that form a square matrix is wasteful. Just loop over the square matrix's size and stop when it doesn't fit any more. Also, when you test whether a matrix is symmetric, the test `a[i][j] == a[j][i]` is only useful if `i` and `j` are the indices of the sub-matrix; you must adjust these indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the sub-matrices, whether are they beeing tested or printed, should be square, so I'd use a different signature than OP's. Take for example this helper function which prints out a sub-matrix, given a bigger matrix passed with VLA notation, a starting point (indices of the top left corner) and a size:

```
void print_submatrix(int cols, int m[][cols],
                     int first_row, int first_col, int n)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < n; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < n; ++c) {
            printf("%3d", m[first_row + r][first_col + c]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

This should help us finding the correct formulas to evaluate the indices in the function that checks symmetry.

```
int is_symmetric(int cols, int matrix[][cols],
                 int first_row, int first_col, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
        //       ^^^^^^^^^ I'll loop only through half the sub-matrix

            if (    matrix[first_row + i][first_col + j]
                 != matrix[first_row + j][first_col + i] ) {
                //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                //         Note that the starting point (top left corner) is fixed,
                //         while the offset is changing        
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The outer loops could be rewritten too

```
void find_sym_submatrices(int rows, int cols, int matrix[][cols])
{
    // For every possible top left corner...
    for (int i = 0, mi = rows; i < rows; ++i, --mi) {
        for (int j = 0, mj = cols; j < cols; j++, --mj) {
            // For every possible square matrix (which fits in size).
            const int m = mj < mi ? mj : mi;
            for (int n = 2; n <= m; ++n) {
                if (is_symmetric(cols, matrix, i, j, n) == 1) {
                    print_submatrix(cols, matrix, i, j, n);
                }
                else {
                    break;  // Yeap, there's no need to check the bigger ones.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Live, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/KK8Yojarf).