# Check whether a given Matrix(m*n) has any matrix inside of it that can be transposed

Tags: arrays, c, math, matrix, char

I need to check if I can find inside of given matrix size of 5*8
a matrix that has a transpose and if there is more than one I must find the biggest one.

example of a given matrix

```
1 2 0 3 2 1 0 7
2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
3 4 6 2 5 6 7 6
4 5 7 3 6 8 9 8
6 7 1 4 7 9 0 9
```

in this matrix we can find a matrix 4x4
that has transpose and its the biggest matrix in the main matrix

```
1 2 3 4 
2 5 6 7 
3 6 8 9 
4 7 9 0
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M 4
#define column 5
#define row 8

int main()
{
    int matrixA[5][8];

printf("please enter a matrix to check if there is a transpose matrix\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
        {
            printf("please enter %d row and %d column: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &matrixA[i][j]);
        }
    }
transpose(matrixA, column, row);

}

void transpose(int A[][row], int c, int r)
{
    int matrixAT[M][M];
    

    for (int size = r; size > 0; size--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c - size + 1; j++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b <= r - size; b++)
            {
                printf("Checking Matrix at row: %d , column: %d ,size: %dx%d", j, b, size, size);
                for (int k = j, w = 0; k < size + j; k++, w++)
                {
                    for (int l = b, z = 0; l < size + b; l++, z++)
                    {
                        matrixAT[w][z] = A[k][l];
                    }
                    printf("/n");
                }
                if (IsSymmetric(matrixAT, size))
                    printf("Matrix found");
            }
        }
    }
}
int IsSymmetric(int mat[M][M], int size)
{
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (mat[i][j] == mat[j][i]) flag++;
                

        }
    }
    return flag == size * size ? 1 : 0;
}
```

this is my code i dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: sorry fixed it thanks tho;)

Comment: i dont know how to post my code plus im asking because i dont have a solution otherwise i wouldnt be here asking the question what your saying make no sense to me anyway chill:)

Comment: All matrices have a transpose.  It appears that you are trying to find a sub-matrix that is equal to its transpose.

Comment: Every matrix could be transposed. Seems you mean matrix symmetric against its main diagonal

Comment: @WilliamPursell i dont know if that is how to tag someone but yes im trying to do what you said im just bad at explaining it in english sorry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67094298/c-find-sub-symmetric-matrix-in-one-big-matrix. Have not marked as duplicate for now because more effective algorithms should exist (seems cubic one)

Comment: @MBo i love you works all i have to do now is to get the biggest Trans matrix and print it and than ill check what i have done on my code compared to his thanks alot bro

Comment: I added working `O(n^3)` solution to my answer

Comment: @Spektre ya i saw that thanks a lot if better than the other one much faster and much easier to understand by the way i tried to vote up the answer but i am new to the platform it says i cant do it but thanks a lot i appreciate that

Comment: @Nathan yep you need to earn more rep ... to unlock features ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IsSymmetric` is slow as it always check all elements why not stop on first inequality instead? Also copying it to temp array again and again ...

The main problem is You are not checking every position and size as you call `transpose(matrixA, column, row);` only once outside the loops ...

Also your main does not return anything and its declared as int ...

I would start with brute force like this:

```
#define column 5
#define row 8
int IsSymmetric(int mat[column][row], int i0,int j0,int size) // check n*n sub matrix at i0,j0 no need to copy again and again to temp array
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
      if (mat[i0+i][j0+j] != mat[i0+j][j0+i]) return 0;
    return 1;
    }
int min(int a,int b){ return (a<b)?a:b; } // not sure if min is present in your environment if is comment this line out
int main()
    {
    int matrixA[5][8];
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
      for (int n = 1; n <= min(column-i,row-j); n++)
       if (IsSymmetric(matrixA,i,j,n))
        {
        // here do what you want with the i,j,n*n sub matrix
        // like remember position and size for the biggest n
        }
    ...
    return 0; // return value as you declared int main
    }
```

Hope I did not make any typo in here as I just wrote this into answer editor from your original code.

How ever as you can see its `O(n^4)` complexity (on average `O(n^3)`) which is really slow. However for your small matrix its not a problem.

In case you need something faster then we need to know more about the data ... for example what is the range of the values? Some hints:

- on positive IsSymmetric test one cell bigger submatrix without testing the previous elements again (recursively increasing diagonal).
- use histogram to detect values that might be only on diagonals (appear once globally or odd times locally)

Using the incremental symmetry test results in `O(n^3)` solution:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define column 5
#define row 8
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void submatrix_print(int mat[column][row], int i0,int j0,int n,int m)
    {
    int i,j;
    printf("%i*%i at %i,%i\r\n",n,m,i0,j0);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++,printf("\r\n"))
     for (j=0;j<m;j++)
      printf("%1i ",mat[i0+i][j0+j]);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void submatrix_print_transposed(int mat[column][row], int i0,int j0,int n,int m)
    {
    int i,j;
    printf("%i*%i at %i,%i\r\n",n,m,i0,j0);
    for (i=0;i<m;i++,printf("\r\n"))
     for (j=0;j<n;j++)
      printf("%1i ",mat[i0+j][j0+i]);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int min(int a,int b){ return (a<b)?a:b; }
int submatrix_symmetric(int mat[column][row], int i0,int j0) // returns biggest symetric submatrix size >=1 found at i0,j0
    {
    int i,n,N;
    N=min(column-i0,row-j0);    // max size that still fits into matrix
    for (n=2;n<N;n++)           // test all sizes above 1
     for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)         // only test newly added cells to last sub matrix
      if (mat[i0+n-1][j0+i]!=mat[i0+i][j0+n-1])
       return n-1;              // first non match means last tested size i svalid
    return n;                   // no mismatches mean full size is valid
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
    {
    int mat[5][8]=
        {
        1,2,0,3,2,1,0,7,
        2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,
        3,4,6,2,5,6,7,6,
        4,5,7,3,6,8,9,8,
        6,7,1,4,7,9,0,9,
        };
    submatrix_print(mat,0,0,5,8);
//  submatrix_print_transposed(mat,0,0,5,8);

    int i,j,n,i0=0,j0=0,n0=0;
    for(i=0;i<column;i++)
     for(j=0;j<row;j++)
        {
        n=submatrix_symmetric(mat,i,j);
        if (n0<n){ n0=n; i0=i; j0=j; }
        }
    submatrix_print(mat,i0,j0,n0,n0);
    return 0;
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The result of the code is:

```
5*8 at 0,0 // input matrix
1 2 0 3 2 1 0 7 
2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 
3 4 6 2 5 6 7 6 
4 5 7 3 6 8 9 8 
6 7 1 4 7 9 0 9 

4*4 at 1,3 // biggest symmetric sub matrix found
1 2 3 4 
2 5 6 7 
3 6 8 9 
4 7 9 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function that check if the matrix ican be transposed or no
and another function that take evry time a part from the main matrix and you move it everytime and check it with 1st function
example :
1st matrix :m[1][1] starting from zero
1 2
2 3
2 matrix :m[2][2] starting from one
2 0
3 4
then when you finish with 2 demension matrix you go to 3
till the end
i hope you understand me and sorry for my bad english